# How did he get married and father a child while in Africa

Tags: south-africa

My great-grandfather's Military History Sheet has him serving in Africa when he was supposed to have married my great-grandmother and fathered his first child - how could this be?

```
Country     From        To           Years  Days
Home    29 Sep 1890     10 Nov 1891     1   42
India   11 Nov 1891     19 Nov 1897     6   8
Home    20 Nov 1897     22 Oct 1898     0   324
Africa  23 Oct 1898     28 Aug 1902     3   309
Home    29 Aug 1902     29 Sep 1902     0   31
```

According to the church marriage register, the marriage was on the 30 Apr 1899 in Hoxton, London. The first child was born on 14 Mar 1900.

So I can accept that the "fathering" was achieved on the same day as the marriage but how can he be in Africa and England at the same time? Even popping back would have been difficult with no airplanes in 1899 - am I missing something?

He was in the Commissariat and Scottish Rifles.

On the marriage document his profession is his civilian job, but on the baptism document he is listed as a Soldier - also the birth certificate for the same child shows him as his civilian job.

Comment: Did his wife visit him? Was he on leave? How are you sure that your great-grandparents did not meet during that time? Do you have any other documents for that time that can flesh out the timeline?

Comment: Have you looked for emigration/immigration/passenger records that might document a trip from Africa to England and back?

Comment: You both raise valid suggestions. The marriage was in London. I have added more information to the question.

Comment: How certain are you that the person with name X who is on the birth certificate, baptism, and marriage documents is the same individual as the person with name X who served in India and Africa?

Comment: Have you looked at the British Newspaper Archive, or looked for regimental histories?  I'm assuming you're looking at the summary of military service in a Chelsea Pensioner's record? For the British Army family I'm researching, someone has written on the record that the soldier's wife accompanied him on his service.   Did either the Commissariat or  Scottish Rifles keep their own records of baptism, burials, and marriages (as I found for my Royal Artillery family)? I would use caution because it's very easy to get records for same-name soldiers crossed up.

Comment: If he was in the Commissariat, it might be that his duties involved accompanying military shipments between the UK and (South?) Africa. Neither that nor Leave will show up on the History Sheet.

Comment: Incidentally, I think that I have read that military transports did not leave passenger lists in the same way that civilian shipping did. No need, I guess. If small groups or individuals travelled on civilian ships, they would appear on those lists .

Comment: @AdrianB38 passenger lists for military transports may not exist as a separate record set (they sometimes are in the USA), but could the information be recorded as part of another record collection such as diaries or minute books, and if so, where? I haven't reviewed the guides at TNA to see if WO records might have this information.  (Note that I've heard researchers from the UK state that the US did not keep War Diaries.  In the US they are called morning reports. Knowing the right keywords to search is essential.) If a soldier changed location wouldn't the info have been recorded somewhere?

Comment: @JanMurphy - I have failed to discover if there are any War Diaries for the (2nd) Boer War, which seems likely to be the context here. But if they are like WW1 Diaries, they are unlikely to record individuals but would record when a unit moved. Muster Rolls are another candidate for detailed location data but they appear to have stopped just before the period in question. I'm sure that if a soldier went on leave, then the office would keep records. But I have never seen evidence that such info still exists. Maybe Commissariat records are the best possibility?

Comment: Re "Commissariat" - Having read around, I'm a little wary of this term being used in this period. So far as I can see, the British Army Commissariat had disappeared by 1888 with the formation of the Army Service Corps, which took on those functions. However, the Army is notorious for continuing with obsolete names and I suspect it entirely possible that the word continued in use for that sort of work. However, I suggest that if no "Commissariat" records can be found, then the ASC records should be consulted to see what they were doing at this time. Dunno what those records are though!

Comment: @AdrianB38 And as always, there's the problem of what records were kept (what was deemed disposable vs. designated as permanent).

Answer (score 3):

Prompted by some of your comments, I looked again at the records and in doing so I found better scans that are more readable (the original were a blur)!
One of the documents giving his promotions said:

```
Transferred 23 March 1899
```

The first column (Corps) showed first the SCO Rifles for his rank promotions and A.R. for the transfer. It also gives the same service number as the other documents so I can be sure it is him.

So he didn't waste any time getting married and everything fits!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing 'answers' to 'comments' in your answer, since none of us wrote an answer to your question. Technically we aren't supposed to have discussion in the comments. They're supposed to be used to suggest how questions and answers can be improved.  Congrats on finding the information you wanted!

Comment: Good point, thank you!